# Ambiguous embeding of images in ActionScript3

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4, embed, package, ambiguity

I get this error

```
 PlayButton.as: Error: Can not resolve a multiname reference unambiguously.      
 PlayButton_PlayHoverImg (from PlayButton_PlayHoverImg.as) and 
 buttons:PlayButton_PlayHoverImg (from buttons\PlayButton_PlayHoverImg.as) are available.
```

I have a project folder with buttons folder in it. I store all my button related classes in my buttons folder. However I get an ambiguity error.

I am emebding an image in the PlayButton.as class

```
    [Embed(source = "../../resources/images/play3.png", mimeType = "image/png")]
    private var PlayHoverImg:Class;
    private var playHoverImpl:Bitmap = new PlayHoverImg();
```

So it tells me there is some problem with the image I embed. What could be the problem?

Comment: Try resetting the compiler. If that doesn't work, are you 100% confident you haven't named another embed PlayHoverImg:Class?

Comment: Yes I am 100% there is no other PlayHoverImg class. How can I reset the comipler?

Comment: Maybe you have a backup somewhere and the compiler can see that and is mistaking it for a copy. Try to rename it, does the error go away? There is also the offchance some other error is setting this off, I remember in the older days the compiler wasnt very good at identifying the errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error simply stated is 'PlayButton_PlayHoverImg' is defined by 2 different classes. Either rename it or cast it to remove the ambiguity.

Comment: Read the comments below the question

Comment: yes, he needs to post the code to move further on this. That way we can determine if its a build issue or code issue.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to clean current project to fix this error.